# IN clause in :conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails 2, I want to execute Query

```
PunchingInformation.all(
  :select => "users.id, login, firstname, lastname, 
    sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(punching_informations.punch_in_time))) as 'avg_pit',
    sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(punching_informations.punch_out_time))) as 'avg_pot'",
  :joins => :user,
  :group => "users.id",
  :conditions => { 
    "punching_informations.date between '#{start_date}' and '#{end_date}'", 
    ["punching_informations.user_id IN (?)", employees.map { |v| v.to_i } ]
  }
)
```

But it always return error like

> Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'punching_informations.date between '2012-09-01' and '2012-09-25'' in 'where clause': SELECT users.id,login, firstname,lastname, sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(punching_informations.punch_in_time))) as 'avg_pit',
>                 sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(punching_informations.punch_out_time))) as 'avg_pot' FROM `punching_informations`   INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.id = `punching_informations`.user_id AND  (`users`.`type` = 'User' OR `users`.`type` = 'AnonymousUser' )  WHERE (`punching_informations`.`date between '2012-09-01' and '2012-09-25'` IN ('punching_informations.user_id IN (?)','--- \n- 28\n- 90\n'))  GROUP BY users.id

Need your help.

Comment: do u have `date` column in your `punching_informations` table?

Comment: `punching_informations.date between '2012-09-01' and '2012-09-25' IN ...` is definitely wrong SQL. Seems like conditions are not defined properly.

Comment: your conditions are not actually a hash, though taken in {}. Have you just copied  it from real project, or edited manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you meant (you have array, but taken in curly braces {} like a hash), but it seems ruby treats first string (`"punching_informations.date between '#{start_date}' and '#{end_date}'"`) as a column, and second array, as array of expected values, thus making the invalid IN condition.

Perhaps it would work if rewritten as

```
:conditions => { 
   [ "(punching_informations.date between '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}') AND punching_informations.user_id IN (?)", employees.map { |v| v.to_i } ]
 }
```

or even better

```
:conditions => { 
   [ "(punching_informations.date between ? AND ?) AND punching_informations.user_id IN (?)", start_date, end_date, employees.map { |v| v.to_i } ]
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

add punching_informations.date and punching_informations.user_id in select

:select => "punching_informations.date, punching_informations.user_id, users.id, ....

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful and easier to grasp if you provided some code to it.